# Bootstrap dropdown on hover not working, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to open a dropdown on hover in Bootstrap but somehow it's not working. I suspect that my jQuery code is wrong but I can't figure out what?

Here is my HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="dropdown-filter" data-target="#"  data-toggle="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Filters</button>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
    <li>
        <div class="results-filter">
            Content goes here
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and my jQuery:

```
jQuery('#dropdown-filter').hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeIn();
 }, function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(100).fadeOut();
});
```

It works when I click on top, but not when I hover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jQuery(this).find('.dropdown-menu')` won't work here as `.dropdown-menu` is not a child of `<a>-#dropdown-filter`.

`.find()` searches for children.

Use `jQuery(this).next('.dropdown-menu')...`

Comment: Ah, I knew it! Thank you :)